# UILabel not able to update the label text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

i am new to ios.  I have a viewController, where in there is a notification observer. 
For example

```
-(void) myNotificationObFn:(Notification *)noti
{
  /* Here i am trying to change the text of UILabel, which is not working. 
  ie:
    NSString *ns = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 10];
    mylabel.text = ns;
  */
}
```

How can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: CodaFi, Sorry. I tried allocating new NSString, and trying to assign. Yes, this function is invoked.

Comment: What about the text field, is it nil?

Comment: You don't close comment.

Comment: I'm sure the open ended comment was added for this post, and not in his actual code otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the tag function if you want to change the label

examples :

if you create the label programmatically, set the tag of your label after you create it for the first time

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
[myLabel setTag:1234];
```

if you create the label in your XIB or storyboard, just change the "tag" field

this way, your label get a tag "1234"

after this, if you need to edit this label , on your notification method put this code

```
UILabel *labelfromtag = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:1234]; //this code direct label "labelfromtag" to your "myLabel", so your new label here is actually your old label
NSString *ns = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 10];

labelfromtag.text = ns;
```

good luck :]

edit : also, is this notification reside in the same class / controller as ur UILabel?

Comment: He's not realloc'ing the label at all. That code is perfectly valid if myLabel is an ivar that is alloc'ed in code or an IBOutlet ivar linked to a label in interface builder. There is no need for a tag to store a reference to a label (you can do it that way, but his way is more common).

Comment: ah, my bad, i didn't read correctly, i thought he was reallocating the label, i didn't see that it was an NSString lol, edited

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void) myNotificationObFn:(Notification *)noti
{
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString *ns = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 10];
        labelfromtag.text = ns;
        [labelfromtag setNeedDisplay];
   });
}
```

Comment: thank you... funny thing is that I do the exact same thing in Android

Comment: Why do you need this, since myNotificationObFn is called on the main queue anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Is your label properly wired up in IB? Can you change the text somewhere else in your code (say viewDidLoad for example)?

2 - You don't need to alloc the string since you are not retaining it outside the scope of this method. You can just do:

```
[myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",10]];
```

Comment: No luck, But, Modification of the UILabel text works fine, in non notification function. Not sure why it doesn't work in notification function.

Comment: Are you creating the label in code (ie. [UILabel alloc] or is it an IBOutlet)? When you say changing it in non notification function works fine, are you doing that in the same method/scope where you create the label? My guess is you are not retaining a proper reference to the label outside the scope of where you create it.